# jQuery input argument is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the HTML markup

```
<input class="youremail" name="youremail" >
```

JS is

```
function changeBackground(agru){
     $('input[name=' + agru + ']').css('background', 'red');
}

changeBackground(youremail);
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: youremail is not defined

my function doesn't work, do I need to convert `agru` to a string?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are not passing in a string.

```
changeBackground(youremail);
```

It sees `youremail` as a variable and that variable is not defined. Add the missing quotes and it will work.

```
changeBackground("youremail");
                 ^         ^
```